# How to GET application by appId using Microsoft Graph API via Java using HttpURLConnection

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, httprequest, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to authorize an OAuth JSON Web Token granted by Azure Active Directory, and one thing I need to do is get more information about the application in the token's appId using the Microsoft Graph API.

Microsoft Graph API allows me to GET an app by its id via

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{id}
```

, but NOT by its appId via

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{appId}
```

The best way I see to use Microsoft Graph API to GET an app using its AppId is via a filter like so:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?filter=appId eq '{appId}'
```

The above filter works just fine in the Microsoft Graph Explorer, but when calling the Graph API using a GET request using HttpUrlConnection, my request fails with HTTP Code 400 and message "Bad Request".

It's weird because using the exact same HttpUrlConnection to GET the full range of applications via

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications
```

works just fine.

Is there something about the filter functionality that I can't use it in a Microsoft Graph API GET request? How should I get info on an app by its AppId?

Here is a snippet of the Java code I am using for my HttpURLConnection:

```
url = new URL(String.format("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?filter=appId eq '%s'", appId));
        final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.getAccessToken());
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        final int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (httpResponseCode == 200 || httpResponseCode == 201) {
            BufferedReader in = null;
            final StringBuilder response;
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                response = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            return json.toString(4);
        } else {
            return String.format("Connection returned HTTP code: %s with message: %s",
                    httpResponseCode, conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should URLEncode the query parameters.

```
String url2=URLEncoder.encode("$filter=appId eq '{applicationId}'");
URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?"+url2);
```

Comment: Thank you! Oddly, instead of encoding, I had to do URL url = new URL(stringUrl.replaceAll(" ","%20")); but this lead me to the correct solution

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else comes looking for this, if you are using the [`GraphServiceClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS) you can do this:

```
var appId = "some app id";

var response = await _graphClient.Applications
    .Request()
    .Filter($"appId eq '{appId}'")
    .GetAsync();

var azureAddApplication = response.FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new ArgumentException($"Couldn't find App registration with app id {appId}");
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is searching this... the API call should be done with the app's Object ID, not the app ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up a single application by its app id using the `/applications` endpoint like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications(appId='{appId}')
```